# Spring sending array of data

Tags: spring, forms, reactjs, typescript, fetch

I have a controller action which expects 2 parameters

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public boolean registration(UserEntity u,@RequestBody List<String> specs) {
    return userManager.register(u ,specs );
}
```

The first one is an entity and as a second parameter I want to send additional list of specializations (in this case array of strings ), but however I am unable to retreive the list of strings, on the javascript side the request is made so by sending formdata and via fetch:

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("addressCity",user.addressCity);
    formData.append("addressHouseNumber",user.addressHouseNumber);
    formData.append("addressState",user.addressState);
    formData.append("addressStreet",user.addressStreet);
    formData.append("email",user.email);
    formData.append("firstName",user.firstName);
    formData.append("isAdmin",user.isAdmin);
    formData.append("lastName",user.lastName);
    formData.append("password",user.password);
    formData.append("phoneNumber",user.phoneNumber);
    formData.append('specs',this.CheckedSpecializations.map(q=>q));


fetch(HttpClient.BaseUrl + url,
        {
            method:'POST',
            body:formData,
            headers:new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'})
        })
```

Comment: Isn't `UserEntity u` part of the request body too? You might want to wrap both `UserEntity` and `List<String>` and accept a single  `@RequestBody`.